# “Invalid Nonce” in registration form ultimate member error

Tags: wordpress, ultimate-member

I am using ultimate member plugin for user registration and login when I am trying to register with plugin it gives me an error Invalid Nonce. But the plugin is working on localhost.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is caused by an expired nonce. It's part of the security features of this plugin, but it can conflict with the Wordpress caching mechanism, especially when using Wordfence.

You should exclude the pages used within Ultimate Member plugin (e.g. register, password reset) from the cache.

[Here is the link to the FAQ entry on the plugin website](http://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/230-invalid-nonce-in-registration-form), providing the information I used to answer this question.

Comment: The link is broken but available at Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20180120155854/http://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/230-invalid-nonce-in-registration-form